# Is the right to free travel somehow covered in the First Amendment?

Tags: us-constitution, travel

Could travel be a way to express oneself?

Comment: I'm curious to know why someone downvoted this question.

Comment: What do you mean by "free" in your question title?  Do you mean "unhindered" or "paid for by someone else"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that the "leading" source of Freedom of Movement is the [Privileges and Immunities Clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privileges_and_Immunities_Clause) (Art. IV, S.2 , Cl. 1) of the US Constitution, that "The Citizens of each State shall be entitled to all Privileges and Immunities of Citizens in the several States". See [Crandall v. State of Nevada, 73 US 35](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/73/35/case.html): "We are all citizens of the United States, and as members of the same community must have the right to pass and repass through every part of it without interruption, as freely as in our own states" (quoted from an earlier case); [US v. Wheeler](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/254/281/), 254 U.S. 281

> In all the states, from the beginning down to the establishment of the
>   Articles of Confederation, the citizens possessed the right, inherent
>   in citizens of all free governments, peacefully to dwell within the
>   limits of their respective states, to move at will from place to place
>   therein, and to have free ingress thereto and egress therefrom

citing the Privileges & Immunities clause as the constitutional foundation.

However, [this article](https://www.bu.edu/law/journals-archive/bulr/documents/wilhelm.pdf), sect. IB notes a number of additional constiutional sources:

> Various Justices at various  times  have  suggested  no  fewer  than 
>   seven  different  sources:  the  Article IV Privileges and Immunities
>   Clause, the Fourteenth Amendment Privileges   and   [sic]   Immunities
>   Clause,   a   conception   of   national   citizenship  said  to  be 
>   implicit  in  the  structural  logic  of  the  Constitution  itself,
>   the Commerce Clause, the Equal Protection Clause, and each of the Due
>   Process Clauses.

[Edwards  v.  California,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwards_v._California) 314 U.S. 160 relates freedom of movement to the Commerce Clause, [Aptheker v. Sec’y of State](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/378/500/case.html), 378 U.S. 500 points us to the Due Process clause. The argument hasn't apparently been made based on the First Amendment, since there are better arguments.